# Elastic search REST query returning more than expected

Tags: elasticsearch

In order to search for the exact string : `"AGA>23/180@20210212"` I've tried the below `match` queries :

```
{"query": { "match" : {"mid": "AGA>23/180@20210212"}}}
{"query": {"bool": { "must" : [ { "match" : { "mid": "AGA>23/180@23221"}}]}}}
```

elastic search matches on `"AGA>135/880@20210212"` & `"AGA>212/880@20210212"`

So it seems the values `135` & `212` are treated like wildcards.

If I use `query` instead: `{"query": { "term" : {"mid": "AGA>23/180@20210212"}}}`
then 0 results are returned.

How to search for value `"AGA>23/180@20210212"` only ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The [term query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html) returns documents that contain an exact term in a
> provided field.

By default [standard analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) is used. It will provide grammar based tokenization for `AGA>23/180@20210212` and will generate the following tokens.

`aga`, `23`, `180`, `20210212`

Due to this, the match query matches on `"AGA>135/880@20210212"` & `"AGA>212/880@20210212"`

To search for the exact term you need to add .keyword to the `mid` field (if you have not explicitly defined any mapping for the field). This uses the keyword analyzer instead of the standard analyzer (notice the ".keyword" after `mid` field). Try out this below query -

```
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "mid.keyword": "AGA>23/180@20210212"
    }
  }
}
```

OR you can change your index mapping to

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "mid": {
        "type": "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```